# How can my Kobold carry all his weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, encumbrance

Carrying capacity, as defined on page 176 of the PHB is:

> Carrying Capacity. Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don’t usually have to worry about it.

My Kobold Barbarian has a 16 in strength, meaning he can carry up to 240 lbs encumbered or 80 lbs unencumbered. He currently is carrying a Greatsword, 2 Handaxes, 4 Javelins, 2 Scimitars, 2 Sheilds, and an Herbalism Kit, which all equates to 39 lbs total (all of which are the standard size for the item). I know I can carry everything, but how would the mechanics work, especially with the large size of all the gear opposed to my 2'6" character

Comment: Is the linked, duplicate question ([Where do adventurers keep all their stuff?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49988/14878)) the same as what you're asking? If not then I'm not sure I fully understand what your actual question is. You already state that you *can* carry all the stuff so it doesn't appear as if you asking about that. If this isn't a duplicate then please clarify what it is you're asking.

Comment: Or are you asking about the size of the weapons in relation to the size of the kobold i.e "how can a 2'6" kobold carry around several weapons that are as big, if not bigger, as it (without constantly getting tripped up or something)"? After re-reading it a couple of times that does seem to be what you're asking but I think it still needs a little bit of clarity.

Comment: Aren't Kobolds Small creatures?  Small creatures have disadvantage with heavy weapons, including a greatsword.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, but due to the pack tactics feature, I get advantage whenever an ally is within 5 feet of my target, so it cancels out.

Answer (score 5):

### D&D is not a physics simulator

> how would the mechanics work

As you describe - you can carry everything. The mechanics of D&D 5e don’t care if it’s practical IRL for a 2’6” tall creature to carry a 6’ long great sword plus all that other stuff

Just like they don’t make a distinction between a 240lb lead ball (about 1/3 of a cubic foot) and a 240lb helium balloon (about 23,200 cubic foot) - both encumber the character equally despite the fact that the helium would lift any character weighing less than about 1,600 lbs if this was the real world. Which it isn’t.

D&D rules opt for simplicity over simulation. If you don’t like that, feel free to make up your own house rules.